# Prolog add certain items to list

Tags: list, prolog, accumulator

I'm unable to figure out why my code isn't working despite looking through answers to similar questions. I'm too new at Prolog to properly name things, but I hope you can see what I'm trying to get at.

I am defining a timetable roughly based on this program and am struggling with getting a list of the Classes that Mike teaches for a given result (Next step will be to declare that only results where both Mike and Phil teach 2 should be returned, but I want to work through it so that I can see and understand what's going on).

I imagine this should be simple but any combinations of the `addToList(List,C)` predicate never work. I know there is the append predicate but I hear it's inefficient, and would like to learn the 'raw' way. I don't know how many variations I've attempted and can't get my head around the way Prolog works in this regard and don't know on what level I'm going wrong - it's all a bit of a black box mystery working with it.

```
        var program = 
        :- use_module(library(lists)). 
            prefers(may,a). 
            prefers(may,b). 
            prefers(may,c). 
            prefers(may,d). 

            prefers(bob,a). 
            prefers(bob,b).
            prefers(bob,c).

            prefers(pete,a). 
            prefers(pete,b).
            prefers(pete,c).
            prefers(pete,d).

            prefers(tom,a). 
            prefers(tom,b).
            prefers(tom,c).
            prefers(tom,d).

            teacher_pref(mike,a).
            teacher_pref(mike,b).
            teacher_pref(mike,c).

            teacher_pref(phil,b).
            teacher_pref(phil,c).
            teacher_pref(phil,d).

            addToList([C|List],C):- addToList(List,C).

            timetable([a,[C1,S1,T1],b,[C2,S2,T2],c,[C3,S3,T3],d,[C4,S4,T4]],List1):-

                teacher_pref(T1,C1),
                teacher_pref(T2,C2),
                teacher_pref(T3,C3),
                teacher_pref(T4,C4),

                prefers(S1,C1),
                prefers(S2,C2),
                S1\\=S2,
                prefers(S3,C3),
                S1\\=S3,
                S2\\=S3,
                prefers(S4,C4), 
                S1\\=S4,
                S2\\=S4,
                S3\\=S4,

                addToList(List1,C):-
                    teacher_pref(mike,C).

    session.consult( program );
    session.query('timetable([C1,[a,S1,T1],C2,[b,S2,T2],C3,[c,S3,T3,L3],C4,[d,S4,T4]],List1).')
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you have:

```
teacher_pref(mike,a).
teacher_pref(mike,b).
teacher_pref(mike,c).
```

And you want to get a list of these classes, which would be:

```
[a, b, c]
```

In Prolog we have some higher-order predicates that are for occasions like this:

```
%        (What to find, the goal to call, all the results)
?- findall(Class, teacher_pref(mike, Class), Classes).
Classes = [a, b, c].
```

In the [Tau-Prolog docs](http://tau-prolog.org/documentation/prolog/builtin/findall/3) they're under **All Solutions**, in [SWI-Prolog there's a couple more](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=allsolutions).

To make this into a more generic predicate:

```
teacher_prefs(Teacher, Prefs) :-
    findall(Pref, teacher_pref(Teacher, Pref), Prefs).
```

Comment: Aja Hammerly has a [conference talk on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hEOVcLAPRG8) where she goes through a similar task: pairing for pair-programming, you might find it interesting!

Comment: Thanks, in the end I did use exactly what you suggested with `findall`, passing the whole predicate. But now, the quickest ended up creating lists of `[T1,L1],[T2,L2],...` where `[T1,L1]\=[T2,L2]...`, and counting against where the T is a given name. The count was really what I was after.